# Prove that linear operator is continuous if the map of every null sequence is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Lambda: X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator, Assume that for every sequence $x_n \rightarrow 0$, the sequence $(\Lambda x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded. Prove that $\Lambda$ is continuous.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\varLambda$ is continuous if and only if $\varLambda$ is continuous at $0 \in X$
If $\varLambda$ is not continuous at $0$，there exists $\epsilon ＞0$，and $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty},st.x_n \to 0，\forall n,x_n\neq 0$and
$$ ||f(x_n) ||\ge \epsilon$$
Then Let $y_n=\frac{x_n}{\sqrt {||x_n||}}$，then $y_n\to 0$，but
$$||f(y_n)||\ge \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{||x_n||}}$$ is unbounded,a contradiction.